# What to do with invalid bounty question?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I've recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286977/uikeyboarddidhidenotification-and-uikeyboarddidshownotification-only-fire-when-t). It didn't receive much attention, so I decided to put up a fifty-point bounty since I was getting desperate. It received some attention, and received two upvotes, however, it did not receive any answers.

A few days later, I made a fresh checkout of code and realized that the problem no longer occurred (this despite the fact that they are absolutely the same code).

To quote my comment:

> Um... Hi, guys. The bounty has ended and I still had no progress with
>   the problem at hand. Shortly thereafter, I decided to do a fresh
>   checkout and miraculously, the issue no longer exists. I am not sure
>   now on what to make of the question. Any ideas?

I've flagged it for moderator attention days ago, but no action has been done yet.

Should I delete the question? Do something else? What about the bounty? If possible, I'm interested in having my reputation refunded, after all, nobody was awarded the 50 rep.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Louis's comment, now I understand that the 50 points deducted from me was also a sort of toll so I can put my question up on priority over others -- it wasn't a payment for the answer. So I'm no longer looking for a refund, so to speak. I paid and got what I paid for.

**EDIT:**

As advised, the question is now **deleted**.

Comment: Can the people who looked at your question have their time refunded?

Comment: I see your point. Could you put up an answer in line with that? Now I understand that the 50 points deducted from me was also a sort of toll so I can put my question up on priority over others. That's a good way of looking at it. But what do I do with the question now?

Comment: @Louis, BTW, I love your goggles. Sorry, off topic. I couldn't help it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard answer to your question is that you're paying for people's attention. It is like paying for an advertisement in a newspaper. If it turns out that you abandon trying to sell whatever you were trying to sell, the newspaper won't refund you.

There's also the fact that by putting a bounty, you've taken the stance that your question is worthy of the attention of the other users. There should be a cost to taking this stance if it turns out that the question was not, after all, worthy of their attention.

Deletion would seem quite advisable in this case since you say that the problem ceased to occur and you don't really know why. In other cases, posting a self-answer would be advisable but not here.

Comment: upon deletion of the question, I received a notification prompting the gain of 40 rep. I investigated and it seems that the bounty was refunded. Is this correct?

Comment: @brain56 No, deleting the question won't refund an expired bounty.  What was the message in the reputation log for that entry?

Comment: @brain56 If your bounty was refunded that's news to me. Every single time I've read a diamond-moderator talk about refunds they were saying "no refunds unless extraordinary circumstances". The doc about bounties is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). I've checked it again and it says no refunds. So...

Comment: It's peculiar. It doesn't say anything, just +40. I can verify that my SO rep as of this writing is 584, whereas it displays as 544 in meta. http://i.imgur.com/oMPGaiz.png

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to have the bounty refunded.  Bounties pay for attention, not answers.  You got your attention, regardless of whether or not it resulted in an answer.

Given your description of the resolution your question should clearly be closed with the reason:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.